# Plugin Stopmotion Preview fails to start in Entangle 2.0

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, gtk

https://github.com/manuq/stopmo_preview

gives the following Error-Code:

```
AttributeError: 'CameraManager' object has no attribute 'get_builder'
```

help() for CameraManager-Object:

```
class CameraManager(gi.repository.Gtk.ApplicationWindow, Progress)
 |  CameraManager(*args, **kwargs)
 |  
 |  :Constructors:
 |  
 |  ::
 |  
 |      CameraManager(**properties)
 |      new(app:Entangle.Application) -> Entangle.CameraManager
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      CameraManager
 |      gi.repository.Gtk.ApplicationWindow
 |      gi.overrides.Gtk.Window
 |      gi.repository.Gtk.Window
 |      gi.repository.Gtk.Bin
 |      gi.overrides.Gtk.Container
 |      gi.repository.Gtk.Container
 |      gi.overrides.Gtk.Widget
 |      gi.repository.Gtk.Widget
 |      gi.repository.GObject.InitiallyUnowned
 |      gi.overrides.GObject.Object
 |      gi.repository.GObject.Object
 |      gi._gi.GObject
 |      gi.repository.Atk.ImplementorIface
 |      gi.repository.Gtk.Buildable
 |      gi.repository.Gio.ActionGroup
 |      gi.overrides.Gio.ActionMap
 |      gi.repository.Gio.ActionMap
 |      Progress
 |      gobject.GInterface
 |      builtins.object
 |
```

No 'get_builder' method anywhere. Who should own this method?

I didn't find any docs for gi.repository.Entangle etc. I think CameraManager is a Gtk.Windows object, a Builder object holds references to all created windows and 'get_builder' shold give the link?

Thanks for any ideas